# In Analytics, can I see page view stats broken down by AdWord ad-network websites?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

In AdWords, under 'Campaigns->Networks' tab I can see which sites on the Ad-Network generated clicks.

I've got auto-tagging enabled.

I want to find a report in Analytics that breaks down each of those websites I see in the AdWords report, and provide me page view, time on site, and bounce rate statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean the placements report that can be found in Analytics by navigating to `Advertising > AdWords > Placements`.

Comment: Bingo! That was the goldmine of information I was looking for! Thank you!